# Accept - Reject of Normal Distribution with prior Cauchy

Tags: bayesian

If $X \sim N(\theta,1)$ with Cauchy as robust prior

$$\pi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+\theta^2)} \qquad -\infty < \theta < \infty$$

how to do the rejection sampler in R, and use it to generate 10, 000 samples from the posterior distribution. with using R function 'rcauchy' to simulate from π(θ); $\pi$($\theta$) is a proposal distribution.

Kindly please help

Comment: " r function rcauchy" needs clarification.

Comment: Why do you need to use rejection sampling here? You can just generate $10{,}000$ samples $\{\theta_1, \dots,\theta_{10{,}000}\}$ from the Cauchy distribution and then simulate $\{X_1, \dots, X_{10{,}000}\}$ by simulating $X_i \sim N(\theta_i, 1)$.